# Laravel - Subscription System (Premium user) + eCommerce system

Tags: php, laravel, e-commerce, laravel-5.6

I have completed a project on Laravel 5.6 with roles (i have a roles table). I would like to implement payment system in the project. I want to achieve two functionalities.

1. Professionals (role) can subscribe to a monthly subscription and get access to premium features of the website like offering their services on the platform, write articles, etc.
2. Every service the professional adds will have a price associated with it, just like a product. And a normal user(role) can subscribe to that user and pay for it. Once the user pay's for it he will be able to get the services from him like sharing files, etc with that professional.  And the amount that he is paid will go to the professional and not our site.

Currently i have one thing in mind. Create a subscription system with Cashier and ecommerce system where with products i would add an extra table called services. And would provide the same functionality of product to service. And use recurring payments.

Is this the right way. Or if anyone can suggest me a better way would help me avoid mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a Multi-tenancy and Concierge type Model. 
So,

1. You have Professionals role type user.
2. General Role type user
3. General Role type user will buy / subscribe the Professional's service.

**Based on that analysis I believe you need the following :**

1. A Professionals user table. [The feature, functionality and role permission  will be applied according this role ]
2. A General User table.
3. Now you need a Mapping table where General User's subscription, service. For example : "General User ID 1 " Subscribe the "services ID 99", "services ID 70" and "services ID 25".

This Service ID is the ID that ha been created during the time a "Professionals" created his/her service. 
So that you could easily make the relation which service is offered by which Professionals and which service is subscribed by which general user.

Hope this will help. If you need the DB table feel free to ask. 
Good Luck,

Comment: Could you provide db table because im confused here. Do you mean to use multi auth instead of rbac system. if i create multiple authentication with users guard and professionals guard i guess i do not need rbac right?

Comment: I tried to map the relationship between the Professional's services and General user's subscription of that service. Nothing related with authontication.